# how do I get the window cursor position

Tags: c++, window, screen, cursor-position

This successfully retrieves the screen coordinates but I would like it to display coordinates relative to a particular window that is being moused over:

```
POINT p;
                if (GetCursorPos(&p))
                {
                    std::cout << p.x << "," << p.y << std::endl;
                    //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
                }
```

Can I modify the code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what [`ScreenToClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-screentoclient) does:

```
if (not ScreenToClient(window, &p)) { /* handle error */ }
```

If this is your own window, you'll also be receiving [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) messages that you can use to keep track of the cursor position and won't need to poll for it. Depending what you want this for, there's even [`WM_MOUSEHOVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousehover).